# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Tags: php, html

Hi guys can anyone help to figure out what's wrong in my code it showing unexpected ','

```
    $list1 .= '<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=','#ffff66',';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=','#d4e3e5',';">
    <td>'.$ver.'</td><td>'.$ver2.'</td>
</tr>';
```

Comment: All of those `,` are unexpected because they shouldn't be there.  Why are they?

Comment: Yap that solved my problem OMG sometime little things cause headache . Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`,` is used for passing multiple parameters to `echo`, not for concatenating strings to add to  be stored in a variable. use `.` instead

Comment: Just changing `,` to `.` won't be good enough, since you'll still be missing quotes after `'#ffff66` and `'#d4e3e5`

Comment: my understanding is that the hex colors don't need to be in quotes

Comment: They do have to be quoted, it's CSS but embedded in JS (and HTML), not pure CSS. Look at most of the answers, they are properly quoting the colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it like this, escaping the single quotes in the javascript:

```
$list1 .= '<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=\'#ffff66\';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=\'#d4e3e5\';">
    <td>'.$ver.'</td><td>'.$ver2.'</td>
</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly concatenating the string/escaping the quotes. You had unnecessary commas. My example also uses double quoted strings so you don't need concatenation

```
$list1 .= "<tr onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66;'\"
               onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5'\">
               <td>$ver</td><td>$ver2</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid to escape quotes: you can use the heredoc syntax:

```
$list1 .= <<<EOD
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>$ver</td><td>$ver2</td>
</tr>
EOD;
```

Comment: I think you have an extra single quote just before closing the string

Comment: @JuanMendes: Thanks, removed now.

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
$list1 .= "<tr onmouseover='this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';' onmouseout='this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';'><td>".$ver."</td><td>".$ver2."</td></tr>";
```

working fine for me.